# Identify the last occurance of a subsring in a string, where the substring is from a table. Teradata

Tags: sql, string, find, position, teradata

I have the following problem:

I need to identify the last occurrence of any sub-string given in table A, and return that given value in return in the select statement of another statement. This is a bit convoluted, but here is the code:

```
SELECT TRIM(COUNTRY_CODE)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 POSITION( PHRASE IN MY_STRING) AS PHRASE_LOCATION, CODE 
    FROM REFERENCE_TABLE -- Where the country list is located
    WHERE PHRASE_LOCATION > 0 -- To return NULL if there is no matches
    ORDER BY 1 DESC -- To get the last one 
    ) t1
```

This works when run by it self, but i have large problems getting it to work as part of another queries' select. I need "MY_STRING" to come from a higher level in the nested select three. The reasons for this is how the system is designed on a higher level.

In other words i need the following:

- PHRASE is coming from a table that have a phrases and a code associated
- MY_STRING is used in the higher level select and i need to associate a code with it, based on the last occurring phrase
- Number of different phrases > 400 so no hard coding :(
- Number of different "MY_STRING" > 1 000 000 / day

So far i tried what you can see above, but due to the constraints of the system, i cannot be to creative.

```
Example Phrases: "New York", "London", "Oslo"
Example Codes: "US", "UK, "NO"
Example Strings: "London House, Something street, New York"; "Some street x, 0120, OSL0". 
Desired Outcomes: "US"; "NO"
```

Comment: Can you show some example data & expected result? You probably need a non-equi-join based on this POSITION plus ROW_NUMBER. Is it possible that the same code appears more than once in the PHRASE?

Comment: Phrases can be multiple times yes. Examples have been updated in the main post (In T-3 minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will result in a *product join*, i.e. use a lot of CPU:

```
SELECT MY_STRING
  -- using INSTR searching the last occurance instead of POSITION if the same PHRASE might occur multiple times
  -- INSTR is case sensitive -> must use LOWER 
  ,Instr(Lower(MY_STRING), Lower(PHRASE), -1, 1) AS PHRASE_LOCATION
  ,CODE 
  ,PHRASE
FROM table_with_MY_STRING
LEFT JOIN REFERENCE_TABLE -- to return NULL if no match
ON PHRASE_LOCATION > 0
QUALIFY
   Row_Number() -- return last match
   Over (PARTITION BY MY_STRING
         ORDER BY PHRASE_LOCATION DESC) = 1
```

If this is not efficient enough another possible solution might utilize `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE`/`REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE`: split the address into parts and then join those parts to PHRASE.

Comment: It did need a bit of a rewrite, but the main idea was solid.